# Extending props with the withRouter HOC in Next.js

Tags: javascript, flowtype, next.js

I'm trying to use withRouter HOC helper in the Next.js library.

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

const MyComponent = withRouter(({ router }) => ())
```

This gives a flow error:

```
[flow] property `router` is missing in props [1]. (References: [1])
```

Even though I have the flow types installed for Next.js and withRouter function has the following signature:

```
withRouter: < T > (Component: React$ComponentType < (T & {
  router: Router
}) > ) => class React$Component
```

I thought flow would work out that `router` is injected by withRouter, but that doesn't seem to be the case? How do I fix this type error?

I tried importing the Router type and declaring it as a prop:

```
import { Router } from 'next/router'

type Props = { router: Router }
const MyComponent = withRouter(({ router: Router }: Props) => ())
```

This removes the error, but now I get a different one:

```
Property router is missing in props [1] but exists in object type [2].

 [1] 61│         {typeof query.post !== 'undefined' && <Post />}

 [2] 29│ const Basic = withRouter(({ router }: { router: Router }) => (
```

Comment: I'm no expert here, hopefully you hear from someone that actually knows how this works, but typically where I've dealt with this kind of prop injection I've still had to define the injected props in the flow type I'm using for the props of the component.

Comment: Do you know how I can import Router type from flow-typed/npm/next_v7.x.x.js?

Comment: I've updated the question with declaring the extra prop, but I'm still getting a different error now at he call site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I got this.

`withRouter` is a function typed with generics and is parametrized with T.

There's a section in flow docs about generics: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/.

One way to call such a function is by passing in the T type when calling:

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import type { Router } from 'next/router'

type Props = {}

type PropsWithRouter = Props & {
  router: Router
}

const MyComponent = withRouter<Props>(({ router }: PropsWithRouter) => ())
```

This passes the flowtype check and the component can be used without passing in the Router at the call site.

Comment: Note: this breaks prettier-standard though.. the prettier-standard reformats the code in an incorrect way. But that's a separate issue..

Comment: Actually! I'm still getting

[flow] Cannot create `Post` element because property `router` is missing in props [1] but exists in `Props` [2]. (References: [1] [2])

Comment: Updated the answer to address the issue mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: I dont get it. Why is the know mention of this in the official Next JS docs?

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the types of `withRouter` to this:

```
withRouter: <T: {}>(
  React$ComponentType<{
    ...$Exact<T>,
    router: Router,
  }>,
) => React$ComponentType<T>
```

And on your component file, you'll have to cast the result of enhancing the base component with the outer props, which for now I'm just putting an empty object.

```
const MyComponent = ({ router }) => (/* some jsx */)


export default (withRouter(MyComponent): React$ComponentType<{}>)
```